# Databricks Notebook - Microsoft Azure - Autocompletion is NOT working when attached to cluster

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook, databricks-connect

Databricks Notebook - Microsoft Azure - Autocompletion is NOT working when databricks notebook is attached to cluster.

Can someone please share any pointers to fix this?

[Edited]

I have a couple of clusters, and i see this behaviour of autocomplete NOT working only with one of the clusters! Any pointers on when this can happen?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Databricks autocomplete features to automatically complete code segments as you enter them in cells. This reduces what you have to remember and minimizes the amount of typing you have to do. Azure Databricks supports two types of autocomplete in your notebook: local and server.

Local autocomplete completes words that exist in the notebook. Server autocomplete is more powerful because it accesses the cluster for defined types, classes, and objects, as well as SQL database and table names. To activate server autocomplete, you must attach your attach a notebook to a cluster and run all cells that define completable objects.

You trigger autocomplete by pressing **Tab** after entering a completable object. For example, after you define and run the cells containing the definitions of `MyClass` and `instance`, the methods of instance are completable, and a list of valid completions displays when you **press Tab**.

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks – use notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-use)

Comment: thanks for your response, i get that, but for some reason, in our Databricks environment, 

=> when i attach notebook to cluster, auto-completion is NOT working/suggesting any recommendations...

=> when i detach cluster, static recommendations are working.